# Problems with android GridLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, multiline, android-gridlayout, fill-parent

I have two questions about my GridLayout.

1. Why does the layout extand past the phone when I have said to fill parent, and parent is set to match parent?
2. Why is the third textview (the one that says "Date") getting mumped down? There is a big space between the one that says Reserve and the one that says date.

Thanks!

[image]

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="4"
    tools:context=".GridLayoutActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCabin1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="3"
        android:layout_height="248dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sky_beach" 
        android:background="#222222"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCabint1Title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="72sp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:text="Sky Beach"
        android:textSize="48sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCabinDesc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Dog friendly vacation rental cabin on a scenic mountain river"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btnCabin1Reserve"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:background="#888888"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:text="Reserve"
        android:textSize="36sp" 
        android:padding="10sp"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCabinDesc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:text="Date: "
        android:textSize="36sp" 
        android:padding="10sp"  />


</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a grid view why are you not using relative layout and set your layout relatively.Your second problem is because your are setting your grid row one after another,hence after setting the imageview it sets your textview txtCabinDesc..Try this following code snippet i have tried.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:columnCount="2"
android:rowCount="4" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgCabin1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_rowSpan="3"
    android:layout_height="248dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:background="#222222"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCabint1Title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgCabin1"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:padding="10sp"
    android:text="Sky Beach"
    android:textSize="48sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCabinDesc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgCabin1"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtCabint1Title"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:padding="10sp"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="Dog friendly vacation rental cabin on a scenic mountain river"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btnCabin1Reserve"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgCabin1"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtCabinDesc"
    android:layout_height="60sp"
    android:background="#888888"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:text="Reserve"
    android:textSize="36sp" 
    android:padding="10sp"  />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCabinDesc1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgCabin1"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnCabin1Reserve"
    android:layout_height="60sp"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:text="Date: "
    android:textSize="36sp" 
    android:padding="10sp"  />
```

Also change your id of the last textView because it clashes with your id of description textView.

Comment: Hey, that works.  I've always kind of avoided relative layout, but I can see it is useful. Still one of those funny things where I don't understand why what I did doesn't work. Seems like fill parent should mean fill parent, multiline should mean multiline, and gridview should create extra space. Oh well.

Comment: relative layout seems to be the best layout when u have to set your widgets relatively.Also fillparent attribute is deprecated and match parent is used instead